# SWT TableColumn does not work?

Tags: java, swt, jface, tablecolumn

Can someone explain what is wrong with my code ?
 I want to create a simple swt table.

Eclipse notice that TableColumn is undefined:

```
    TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
```

Here is the complete Code:

```
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(280, 300);
    shell.setText("Testtabelle");

    Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER
        | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    String[] titles = { " ", "C", "!", "Description", "Resource", "In Folder", "Location" }; 
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
      column.setText(titles[i]);
    }

    int count = 128;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
      item.setText(0, "x");
      item.setText(1, "y");
      item.setText(2, "!");
      item.setText(3, "this stuff behaves the way I expect");
      item.setText(4, "almost everywhere");
      item.setText(5, "some.folder");
      item.setText(6, "line " + i + " in nowhere");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      table.getColumn(i).pack();
    }
    table.setSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, 200));
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
```

Comment: What is the **exact** message from Eclipse?

Comment: The Constructor TableColumn(Table,int) is not definied. But I imported org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

Comment: Did you import the correct `TableColumn`, i.e. `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn` and not `javax.swing.table.TableColumn`?

Comment: Try importing it explicitly. And make sure you don't import any other `TableColumn`.

Comment: Thank u soo much :) I imported both :/

Comment: @user3297628 I added an answer, so that it is more prominent. Please accept it if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you import the correct `TableColumn`. In your case, this will be:

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn
```

Also make sure that you don't import any other `TableColumn` if you don't need it. A popular example would be:

```
javax.swing.table.TableColumn
```